# How to remove a SVN Repository (local) from Tortoise SVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have created a Tortoise SVN repo in my C:\Users\***\svn_repo dir and would like to delete it. Is it safe to just delete the directory itself because the TortoiseSVN Explorer utilities don't show me how and neither does the documentation

Answer (score 13):

Just delete the repo. And go to Settings -> Saved Data -> URL history -> Clear.
You'll be fine. I promise

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's safe. A Subversion repository is nothing else than a directory with a bunch of files.

Comment: Wait a minute. I think Asif is asking, after importing a svn repository to the C:\Users\**\svn_repo   FROM an existing remote repository, is it safe to delete the files in the C:\Users\**\svn_repo? Is there any danger of deleting the real remote SVN repo or files ? I tried this and its giving me an exclamation point, it seems as if I commit, the real repo will get files deleted.. This is a question I have. Can anyone answer?

Answer (score 4):

I windows.

- Go to project in explorer.
- Options
- See hidden files.
- Delete SVN folder

Comment: This should be upvoted much more than it is. The .svn folder controls everything, and is the cleanest way to remove SVN control over a folder. I renamed a project folder under SVN (Tortoise SVN) control, then created a folder with the old name for use with git (Bitbucket/Sorucetree). Tortoise put its .svn folder back in there on its own and wanted to control that folder. Removing the .svn folder solved the Tortoise SVN confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the repository browser to delete?  Right click the any folder and choose TortoiseSVN -> Repo Browser.  Then point to your local repository in the URL field.  Once open you could be able to browse the repo, and with a right click, delete the folder.

Comment: tried that, I managed to delete the problem folder, but now my problem is to get ***NetBeans***' SVN up-to date,

Comment: @Asif_Hirai, no clue on the NetBeans front, though in eclipse if i right click the project and refresh it would clear things up.  I would assume NetBeans had something similar.

Comment: Reinstalled TortoiseSVN with CMD Utils, got svn 1.7 with it. Now I can get access to my Google Code Projects through svn

Comment: @Asif_Hirai, can you create a new answer and update it with your answer then tomorrow (you have to wait 24 hours) mark it as the answer so that others can benefit from you experience.